# Why do so many iptables examples specify both "-p tcp" and "-m tcp"?

Tags: iptables

The manual isn't very clear, and the online articles & tutorials don't bother to explain it.

What's the significance of -m tcp and -p tcp used together? It seems so redundant, it bothers me...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using -p tcp, -m tcp shouldn't be necessary.  From the manual page for iptables:

> iptables can use extended packet
>   matching modules.  These are loaded in
>   two ways: **implicitly, when -p or
>   --protocol is specified**, or  with  the -m  or  --match  options,  followed  by the matching module name; after
>   these, various extra command line
>   options become  available,  depending
>   on  the  specific module.